# why won't push_back function insert values into vector with defined size

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++. So, I cannot figure out why vector member function does not insert values into vector.

```
int main (){

    vector<char> v(5);
    char x = 'a';
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        v.push_back(x);
        ++x;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        cout << v[i];

    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't insert elements?

Comment: You start your `vector` at size `5` and *then* `push_back` 5 *more* elements, to a total size of `10`. Is this what you intended? I doubt it.

Comment: this looks like an infinite loop to me, since you're looping until `v.size()` but constantly making `v` bigger

Comment: `v.push_back(x);` should be `v[i] = x;`.

Comment: You increase the size of `v` with `push_back()` every time round the loop so it never ends

Comment: Actually, nothing happens when I run it in Visual Studio. Empty window. it should print out the characters..abcde

Comment: It keeps looping because you keep making the vector bigger than `i` by adding a new element onto the back.

Comment: @dino2018 It doesn't matter what the console output appears to be. The program can do anything as soon as `x` overflows which would only be about 100 iterations in. If you want to see what's happened then you can press the pause execution button in visual studio and inspect the auto s window.

Comment: You should learn to use debugger, it allows step-by step code execution showing content of variables.

Comment: @George Not necessarily; it's implementation-defined whether `char` is `signed` or `unsigned` by default. If it's `unsigned`, then there's no UB.

Comment: @George: and if `char` is a signed type, UB is *undefined*, so continuing indefinitely is perfectly legitimate.

Answer (score 4):

> I cannot figure out why vector member function does not insert values into vector

It does insert the values in the fact. The execution, just doesn't reach the printing of `vector` contents, since the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    v.push_back(x);
    ++x;
}
```

Is an infinite one.

Before the first iteration `v.size()` return `5` (since that is the number of elements, the vector was constructed with), hence the `i < v.size()` during the first iteration evaluate to `0 < 5`.

The loop, then does its thing, by inserting the element into the vector (increasing the `v.size()` by `1` in the process), and increasing `i` by `1`. Hence, the comparison during the second iteration evaluates to `1 < 6`.

It, then, continues, in the similar fashion, towards infinity (or until you kill it).

Comment: Minor poke, the loop is not strictly speaking infinite, as `x` will overflow.

Comment: @George Didn't you mean `i` will overflow, since `x` doesn't impact the loop execution? While, that is true, overflowing `int` is undefined behavior (in addition to, _I think_, converting a unsigned type (`size_t`, that is returned from `std::vector::size` to an `int`, when the value cannot be represented in an `int`). And, once undefined behavior kicks in - all bets are off about correctness about the program. I didn't add such details, since I thought that, they would serve a purpose of confusing the OP, instead of answering the question.

Comment: @George overflow not a problem if the `char` is unsigned. Even if it were, UB could still leave you with an infinite loop.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius `i` would overflow too, just not before `x`. It might be more likely to see weirdness once `i` overflows, but as soon as `x` does, like you say, all bets are off. As far as I know, unsgined -> signed conversion is legal, it would just truncate the value.

Comment: @juanchopanza True (i'm probably being too picky), but the op does say they're using visual studio, `char` is `signed` by default on msvc. And I think it probably is on `clang` too. And yes, UB could leave you with an infinite loop, my point was just that it doesn't have to :). Anyway I won't argue further and just upvote the answer, sorry, i'm definitely being argumentative/too picky.

Comment: @George Well, as juan implied, the fact whether `char` is signed, or not is implementation defined, so it can, theoretically, be unsigned. Such arguments are a positive thing. For instance, I went to a Standard draft, to refresh my memory upon this topic. What I found was: according to section 7.8.3: "If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type; otherwise, the value is implementation-defined." So it is not UB in this case, but rather, implementation defined. But, still, I didn't want to confuse the OP with all of this information.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius "If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type; otherwise, the value is implementation-defined." Thanks for pointing that out :) Thinking about it, my compiler does always scream when doing `signed` -> `unsigned` conversions for things like legacy `vector` types, i've just never really seen it as something concretely bad. Anyway, your answer is good and i've upvoted it, sorry, I was just being argumentative.

Answer (score 0):

@juanchopanza  "Even if it were, UB could still leave you with an infinite loop." - That's *not* how UB works. If a program has UB *anywhere*, the *entire* program is invalid and *any* behaviour is OK. Doing what you intended, an infinite loop, a crash, formatting your harddrive. All are OK results of a program invoking UB.